# How to move a button with a filled combobox?

Tags: c#

How can I let the Button Loop move if the I click on the combobox at number one, then it has to be the same with button1. If that is the same then my button Loop has to move to the button1?

can somebody help me?

this is the code :

```
    private void HaalOp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Programeren\blokboek4\week5\week5toets\week5toets\bin\Debug\Bestemmingen.xml");
            string line = sr.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                Combox.Items.Add(line);
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }



    }

    private void Loop_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (true )
        {

        }



    }

    private void Combox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Combox == "")
        {

        }
    }
```

the buttons are called but1 but2 but3 but4 but 5 but6 and i have a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Take help of `SelectedIndex` property of ComboBox and use that to create ID of Button. Then select control using `this.Controls.Find()`. More details available at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(VS.80).aspx